# Inheritance when initialising NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, core-data

Say I have a subclass of `NSManagedObject` called `MyObject` and a subclass of that called `User`.

Each of these subclasses has a particular insert method called `class func createInManagedObjectContext(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext, propertiesDictionary: NSDictionary) -> User/MyObject?` which itself has uses the `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName` method to insert a new entity.

How do I correctly use inheritance to set the `MyObject` properties in `User` object?

Should I create a new `MyObject` in the `User` method, set the `User` properties from this new object then remove the `MyObject` so it doesn’t get saved? Or am I trying to reinvent the wheel here?

Update with code:

```
class func createInManagedObjectContext(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext, propertiesDictionary: NSDictionary) -> MyObject?
{
    let newObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MyObject", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as MyObject

    newObject.property = propertiesDictionary[“property”]
}




override class func createInManagedObjectContext(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext, propertiesDictionary: NSDictionary) -> User?
{
    let newObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as User

    newObject.name = propertiesDictionary[“name”]
}
```

This is what my code structure looks like. But when I call `createInManagedObjectContext` on `User`, the property ‘property’ in `MyObject` doesn’t get set despite the override keyword being used. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `User` is a subclass of `MyObject`, then any instance of `User` **is** also an instance of `MyObject`. Since `User` inherits from `MyObject`, all `User` instances have all properties defined on `MyObject`.

So you create an instance of `User`, and then set all of its properties, including those that are defined for `MyObject`. You don't need to create two instances to use inheritance.

Update, based on code snippet:

Your `createInManagedObjectContext` is a custom method. It does not get called unless you call it. If you're calling this method on `User`, there's no reason for the `MyObject` version to automatically be called. So, calling the method on `User` will not set `property` in that code.

However, since `User` **is also an instance of** `MyObject`, **you do not need to call that method to set a value for `property`**. You can rewrite the `User` version to look something like this:

```
override class func createInManagedObjectContext(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext, propertiesDictionary: NSDictionary) -> User?
{
    let newObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as User

    newObject.property = propertiesDictionary[“property”]
    newObject.name = propertiesDictionary[“name”]
}
```

Comment: I think my confusion is over the `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` method. As both of the custom initialisers both use this method leading me to assume/think that two objects will get insterted

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed this issue by adding a `label` property, and calling the relevant superclass’s method passing on the label.